# How To Save UILabel Information

Tags: ios, uilabel

I have a calculator that multiplies a value with a certain $ rate. The user can edit the $ rate, and the value is multiplied with the user-entered rate. Here is my code for this:

```
    - (IBAction)edit
    {


        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Edit New Amount"
                                                        message:@"Enter new rate"
                                                       delegate:self
                                              cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
                                              otherButtonTitles:@"Ok", nil];


        alert.alertViewStyle = UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput;
        [[alert textFieldAtIndex:0] setKeyboardType:UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad];

        [alert show];



    }

- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
    {
        if (buttonIndex != alertView.cancelButtonIndex) {

    UITextField *field = [alertView textFieldAtIndex:0];
    field.placeholder = @"Enter New Rate";

    NSCharacterSet * set = [[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"0123456789."] invertedSet];

            if ([field.text rangeOfCharacterFromSet:set].location != NSNotFound)
            {


                UIAlertView *errorAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"Only numbers are allowed in this field."delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK."otherButtonTitles:nil];
                [errorAlert show];

                rate.text=@"";
            }
            else
            {

            rate.text = field.text;
            }
    }

else
{
    //Cancel
}
}
```

However, when the app closes and is restarted, the old rate is displayed, not the new user-entered rate. How can I save the new user-entered rate, so that it is retained within the app, even when it is restarted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the value to be retained after app is closed, then you got to store it somewhere in file system. Easiest and convenient way is to use NSUserDefaults:

```
//Storing in user defaults
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:field.text forKey:RATE_KEY];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

//Retrieving (possibly in app start or viewdidload)
self.rate.text = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:RATE_KEY];
```

One note on usage of NSUserDefaults is that it doesn't support storing every object type, it supports NSString,NSArray,NSNumber etc and primitive types. Since you used NSStrings in your code I assumed you can save it as string to defaults.

Comment: Thanks. I thought it would have to be saved somehow in the file system, but I did not know how to do it. I used the code snippet, but I get an undeclared identifier error with "RATE_KEY."

Comment: that I thought you would use a macro, put `#define RATE_KEY @"rate"` in the beginning of .m file or .h file

Comment: as a general practice I suggest you to use define macros for keys, so that you don't have to remember the exact values and they will be shared when header files are imported

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried creating a new variable to hold the new input as the user enters the new input, and then setting whatever the new input is to that new variable? It sounds like it is restarting from the last variable that was set in the input.

Comment: Wouldn't that variable be "reset" to its original value when the app is restarted?